# What is good practice when saving textual data which contains meta information?

Tags: database-design

This is bugging me for quite a while and even though I decided to do it in a certain way I am still no convinced that I decided well.

Here is the background to it:

One of the core features of my application relies on textual data which will reference other entities in my system. Let's put it into a simple example:

```
This month we sell blue screwdrivers 
and next month red screwdrivers.
```

Here, `blue screwdrivers` and `red screwdrivers` are products which is why they can be encoded like this:

```
<offer id="0">
  This month we sell <product id="13">blue screwdrivers</product> 
  and next month <product id="37">red screwdrivers</product>.
</offer>
```

The `id` is actually a valid ID in my database which will allow me to identify the referenced entity and therefore will also allow me to e.g. link the product in a website to an actual URL.

Now the actual question is what would be the best method to *store* this information. In the end I decided to use a `BLOB` in MySQL to store that data but I could also simply use `VARCHAR(max_file_size)`. Anyway, sure if I really want to save textual data or XML data in my database.

Another problem which comes into play is consistency. Keeping those strings/XML up-to-date will also take some effort. Imagine a user decides to remove a `product` from an `offer` will require additional actions to keep those string up-to-date as well beside the actual relation from the offer to its products. Additionally painful could be any change in terms of specification. Any change that needed to be applied to *all* strings/XML would also be quite an ugly and maybe even dangerous act.

There is an advantage though. XML can be validated using DTD files. So at least when it comes to the validation of a string if it complies to a certain format which I am requesting I can use existing XML parser which are constrained by a given DTD file.

I am still looking for a better solution and I hope to find a good answer by somebody who did something like this and shares his expertise.

Comment: What solution would be suitable depends entirely on what requirements you have to meet. E.g. if you need the XML blobs but those blobs have foreign-keys in the DB, you could model those as a foreign key constraint (even though this duplicates some data). Maybe you don't actually need that XML blob. Or you actually want a document database.

Comment: @amon Would it make sense e.g. to create a constraint function which actually reads the XML file and checks if the contained references comply with the actual relation between `offer` and `product`? This sounds reasonable and terrifying both at the same time to be honest. :D